# Transformation working on small files fails when used with the "--stream" option (required due to file size)

Tags: json, jq

JQ play snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/D5-FZl8wOs

I'm using jq to flatten a json array to be used for sql.

json:

```
{
"0123":[
    {"i":0,"p":"file 1","l":100},
    {"i":1,"p":"file 2","l":200}
    ],
"0234":[
    {"i":0,"p":"file 1","l":100},
    {"i":1,"p":"file 2","l":200}
    ]
}
```

jq:

```
jq -r to_entries[] | {hash: .key, val: .value[]} | [.hash, .val.i, .val.p, .val.l]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  "0123",
  0,
  "file 1",
  100
]
[
  "0123",
  1,
  "file 2",
  200
]
[
  "0234",
  0,
  "file 1",
  100
]
[
  "0234",
  1,
  "file 2",
  200
]
```

The above worked only while the file was small, but now I get memory errors / OS killing it as its grown larger.

If I pass the --stream parameter, I get the error:

`jq: error (at <stdin>:9): Cannot index array with string "i"`

How can I solve this?

Comment: *How* is the size of the file related with the `--stream` parameter? Error seems to say something else.. make sure titles are accurate problem/question representations.

Comment: The first command works if the file is small. It gets killed by the OS now that its grown large.

Comment: To narrow down the problem, I need a way to get `to_entries[]` working with streaming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like following will work **for your sample input**.

```
foreach inputs as $pv ([[],[]]; # [A, B]
  if ($pv|length) == 2          # if pv is a path-value pair
  then .[0] |= if . == []       # if A is empty
    then . + [$pv[0][0],$pv[1]] # add first key from path definition and the value located at path to A
    else . + [$pv[1]] end       # add value to A
  else [[],.[0]] end;           # move A to B's place, leave A empty
  if .[0] == [] and .[1] != []  # if A is empty but B is not
  then .[1] else empty end      # print B
)
```

invocation:

```
jq --stream -n 'foreach inputs as $pv ([[],[]]; if ($pv|length) == 2 then (.[0] |= if . == [] then . + [$pv[0][0],$pv[1]] else . + [$pv[1]] end) else [[],.[0]] end; if .[0] == [] and .[1] != [] then .[1] else empty end)' file
```

jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/Q81EZahkjG

Comment: @thouliha see my updated answer. jqplay doesn't have `--stream` option so you need to replace `inputs` with `tostream` and uncheck null input in order to make it work there

Comment: Wow, this worked great! I don't know how to thank you. I could've *maybe* done this in node/java/rust with streaming, but you're a jq wizard!

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way to get to_entries[] working with streaming

Here's a def that does just that:

```
def atomize(s):
    fromstream(foreach s as $in ( {previous:null, emit: null};
      if ($in | length == 2) and ($in|.[0][0]) != .previous and .previous != null
      then {emit: [[.previous]], previous: $in|.[0][0]}
      else { previous: ($in|.[0][0]), emit: null}
      end;
      (.emit // empty), $in) ) ;
```

With this def, you can use your filter by prepending `atomize(inputs)` assuming you invoke jq with both the `-n` and `--stream` options.  That is, your main filter would be:

```
atomize(inputs)
| to_entries[]
| {hash: .key, val: .value[]}
| [.hash, .val.i, .val.p, .val.l]
```

### Alternative

If the JSON is completely regular, as in the example, you could alternatively write:

```
atomize(inputs)
| to_entries[]
| .value[] as $value
| [.key, $value[]]
```